# Define Chromedriver to be used in run time

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

With current changes in chromedriver, the executable is tightly coupled with a specific version. If the browser version is lower than the target version, it throws exception.

E.g. If we use Driver v.76, it will expect Chrome of version 76 only. For version 75, it will throw an exception.

Can I fetch the browser version before initializing the webdriver, so that I can finalize which chromedriver to be initialized, assuming, I have multiple driver executable supporting different versions of Chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious...how many versions of chrome are you supporting?

Comment: For distributed execution, we are not sure what would be the chrome version in assigned remote desktop. it will be either of 73, 74 or 75. Driver 74 and 75 expects same chrome version to get initialized, so we need some solution to check chrome version, just before the webdriver gets initialized.

Answer (score 0):

could you not get the local version from your machine and store in ENV variable:

MAC:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version
```

Windows:

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" get Version /value
```

Linux:

```
google-chrome --version
```

and from here you define the driver version that is needed or point to an existing driver location.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for this update. Can these be run inside Java class like other terminal commands using Runtime.